# Smoothing error lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some error bars that I've made into an error line like so:

```
cis = []
for row in data:
    cis.append(stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=np.mean(row), scale=np.std(row)))

ci_lower = [ci[0] for ci in cis]
ci_upper = [ci[1] for ci in cis]
cis = [ci_lower, ci_upper]

offsets = np.abs(cis - y[None, :])

plt.fill_between(x, y - offsets[0], y + offsets[1], facecolor=(0.8, 0.8, 0.8))
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=offsets, color=(0.8, 0.8, 0.8))
plt.plot(x, y, 'k', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

It works nicely except that I'd like to smooth at least the error line - it currently looks pretty jaggy - but not sure where to start.

Comment: You have a small typo, missing the close paren for `cis.append(...)`. Also missing `data` and import statements - I can extrapolate, but it'd be good to make it a complete [mcve] :)

Comment: Smooth, how? The (x-axis) resolution is the best you have; anything smoother and you're interpolating the data, not showing the actual data.

Comment: irunno, all I know is that I've been asked to smooth it - I also think it's rather pointless.